# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to route from a child component and facing the error

Parent App.js :-

```
    class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <Header />
        <div >
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={DashBoard} />
              <Route exact path="/create-project" component={CreateProject} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Header.js :-

```
  const Header = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => history.push("/create-project");
  return (
    <>
      <div>Projects</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Create +</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I'm unable to debug despite reading several answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Header component is outside the BrowserRouter and therefore react-router hooks like useHistory doesn't work inside it.

Better:

```
    class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div >
          <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={DashBoard} />
              <Route exact path="/create-project" component={CreateProject} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so I think if you use `react-router-dom`, then just wrap `BrowserRouter`around `<App />` (topmost level) to begin with

Answer (score 1):

Move `<BrowserRouter>` to out side Header:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={DashBoard} />
        <Route exact path="/create-project" component={CreateProject} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<Header />` component is outside your

To fix this issue, you can follow this path:

1. Install [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) with `yarn add history` or `npm i history`. `history` allows you share a single history object across components.

Then you have to create a history object

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

Import `Router` from `react-router-dom` and change `<BrowserRouter>` to `<Router>`

```js
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

Also import the history object you created, and your final code should look like this

```js
 import history from "../../utils/history";
 class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <Router history={history}>
            <Header />
        </Router>
        <div >
          <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={DashBoard} />
              <Route exact path="/create-project" component={CreateProject} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```